# Auto layout + size classes issue in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, size-classes

[image]

In the above view, viewB is a subview of viewA created using an **xib** and the constrains also added in the xib. viewB has constrains top, bottom, leading & trailing relative to its superview. The file owner is swift view controller. viewB is connected with the file owner

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewB: UIView!
```

But when I run the project in iPAD running iOS 8 the viewB is not visible? (in the iPhone it is visible) 
I tried to access its frame in viewdidLoad & viewDidAppear, it is (0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)

This is the only swift view controller in my project, all the other views & VC are in objc.

Is it a bug in swift or am I trying to do something wrong?

Comment: Have you set the top, bottom, leading & trailing constraints for the view A with its superview?

Comment: @diegomen yes, it is programmatically assigned using VFL

Comment: How are these views created? In a xib / storyboard or in code? Are you using size classes? Note also that viewDidLoad is too early to look at frames, you need to wait until layout - though didAppear is fine for that. What's the frame of view A when you check?

Comment: It is created using xib, constrains also added in the xib. I am not using size classes. 
frameOf the viewA = (0.0,128.0,768.0,896.0) in viewDidAppear

Comment: It is visible if I manually set the frame in viewDidAppear

Comment: And if you log `viewA.constraints`, what do you see? It sounds like the constraints aren't there

Comment: I only get the following contains for viewA in viewDidAppear
[<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1768b7f0 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x17699230]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x176ec740 )>, 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1768b820 H:[UIView:0x17699230]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x176ec740 )>, 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1768b850 V:[UIView:0x17699230]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x176ec740 )>]
(sorry for the bad formatting)
These constrains are added programmatically after adding viewA as subview
but there are lot of constrains in the IB? I am not removing anything at build time

Comment: @jrturton I think it is related to size class selection in xib. btw I recreated all the stuffs using objc. think are fine now :)
Thanks you

Comment: @Clement It is good that you found the answer yourself (which is always the better thing to do). But don't add the answer to the question body itself. Please add it as a separate answer. You can answer your own question in SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is resolved.
It was related to size classes in the XIB. One constraint was added to Cw & Rh sizes.
If anyone come across this issue, check the xib's layout constrains twice :)

A good reference : http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2014/08/working-with-size-classes-in-interface-builder/