# Custom tableViewCell in storyboard losing it's auto-layout constraints in iOS8.1

Tags: ios, autolayout, uitableview

The problem is I could get my custom `UITableViewCell`(custom backgroundColor is changed),
but the constraints in it is all lost.

ps. I'm using Xcode 6.1.1.

I want to get the correct height value, but the constraints all lost.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

        static HomeMainNewsCell *mainCell = nil;

        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            mainCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HomeMainNewsCell"];
        });
        [mainCell.titleLabel setText:@"dsfjsdhfjsasdfsdfdsfsdfsdfsdfk"];
        [mainCell layoutIfNeeded];

        CGFloat height = [mainCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
        return height;
}
```

It is the log

```
 po [mainCell.contentView constraints]
<__NSArrayM 0x7fe05b745c10>(

)
```

Here is storyboard screenshot

[image]

Addition info

After I delete the heightForRowAtIndexPath methed, it displays perfect in iOS8.1.

But in iOS7.1 , it displays as every cell's hight value is 44. And the constraints are all back.

```
po [mainCell.contentView constraints]
<__NSArrayM 0x78e50f20>(
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78e52a10 UILabel:0x78e524d0.trailing == UITableViewCellContentView:0x78e52230.trailing - 8>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78e52a40 V:[UILabel:0x78e524d0]-(17)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x78e52230 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78e52a70 H:|-(8)-[UILabel:0x78e524d0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x78e52230 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78e52aa0 V:[UILabel:0x78e52380]-(9)-[UILabel:0x78e524d0]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78e52ad0 UILabel:0x78e52380.trailing == UITableViewCellContentView:0x78e52230.trailing - 8>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78e52b00 V:[UIImageView:0x78e522d0]-(9)-[UILabel:0x78e52380]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78e52b30 H:|-(8)-[UILabel:0x78e52380]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x78e52230 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78e52b60 H:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x78e522d0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x78e52230 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78e52b90 H:[UIImageView:0x78e522d0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x78e52230 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78e52bc0 V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x78e522d0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x78e52230 )>
)
```

Comment: How are the constrains added? Did you try to log cell.constrains?

Comment: @Clement I added them in the Storyboard.And yes, I logged that and found that is the reason why height value is not correct.

Comment: are you using size classes?

Comment: My suggestion is, select each constrains and check the size classes, check are there any constrains added specifically for a particular size

Comment: @Clement The problem is constraints array is empty, but in storyBoard they are all added...

Comment: @Clement I edited and add more info, hopes it could be some hint.

Comment: This might be related to your issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/27354333/1292441

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found a perfect solution.

The reason of this issue is in iOS8 using `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` with autolayout and it works great and better than before.

And the solution post is from here.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=18517

The solution is so cool~~ And thanks the people comments on this question.